# Rails I18n full error messages in RSpec Capybara feature tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, internationalization, capybara

I want to apply validation checks to my feature tests like:

```
click_button 'Submit'

expect(page).to have_content "Question can't be blank"
```

I'm using I18n features and want to generate the message using `t()` helper:

```
expect(page).to have_content t('errors.messages.blank')
```

But this only checks for `"can't be blank"`. But I need to check the error on the `question` field. Why do I need full messages? Indeed, if the only concern was field-related errors, we could cover this with something like:

```
expect(find('.question-wrapper')).to have_content t('errors.messages.blank')
```

But sometimes the errors are on fields that are not used in the form, or on `:base`. Suppose we have a form to enter a question and its answers as nested attributes (it has a "Add new answer" button which creates new sets of `Answer` fields using JavaScript), and expect these errors if the form is submitted without any answers:

```
expect(page).to have_content "There should be at least 2 answers"
expect(page).to have_content "Correct answer must be selected"
```

How to I18n'ize this? We can't check for any of these fields like the above `.question-wrapper` because `"at least 2 answers"` isn't bound to any attribute (or even if it was, say to `answers`, it's not in the form) and the correct answer radio doesn't exist since the form is submitted without any answers (without clicking "Add new  answer" button I've mentioned above).

---

I'm currently using a hacky helper like:

```
# spec/support/helpers/i18n_helpers.rb
def full_error(model_class, attribute, message)
  @_i18n_dummies ||= {}
  @_i18n_dummies[model_class] ||= model_class.new
  @_i18n_dummies[model_class].errors.full_message(
    attribute,
    @_i18n_dummies[model_class].errors.generate_message(attribute, message)
  )
end
```

To do the above expectations:

```
# spec/features/question_spec.rb
expect(page).to have_content full_error(Question, :answers, :many) # A custom validator
expect(page).to have_content full_error(Question, :correct_answer, :blank)
```

The whole thing is at https://gist.github.com/halilim/9c45abdcc50074cad860.

Comment: I would say you probably shouldn't be using t() to generate theses strings in your tests since then you're not actually verifying they are correct, but rather just reimplementing how the error strings are generated in your test code which isn't really testing anything.

Comment: @TomWalpole `t()` is especially useful when you're not testing the content but rather if a specific error was generated. For checking the content you'd need to literally write the content of the message. Actually this is recommended method (by thoughtbot etc., goog Rails i18n testing).

Comment: Ok -but then you really should be testing your i18n translations somewhere else, which seems like extra work to me.  To each their own.

Comment: @TomWalpole I'm not testing translations here, my only concern here is "expect page to have a blank message if something is empty". Since this is a multilingual app and translations might change from time to time, `t()` is less fragile than writing the error message directly in the default language.